# Bootstrap Data-toggle not working on PHP using a "while "

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem whith my " Bootstrap Collapse" . My query display only the fist $ID_Producto of all my rows.

```
<?php

        $Consulta_Productos = $Conexion ->query( "SELECT * FROM productos ORDER BY Producto_Categoria");
        while($Fila_Productos = $Consulta_Productos->fetch_assoc())
        {
            $ID_Producto = $Fila_Productos['ID_Producto'];
        ?>

            <span data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">Show ID <?php echo $ID_Producto ?></span>
            <div id="demo" class="collapse">
                <?php echo $ID_Producto; ?>
            </div>
            <br>

        <?php
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: hello , thank you , I want to click " Show ID" and the data- toggle = "collapse " shows me the correct $ID_Producto , but only shows me the first of all my rows , the others do not work

Comment: that's because your  data-target="#demo" and id="demo" are the same for all the products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `data-target="#demo" and id="demo"` are the same for all the products.

try this

```
<?php

        $Consulta_Productos = $Conexion ->query( "SELECT * FROM productos ORDER BY Producto_Categoria");
        while($Fila_Productos = $Consulta_Productos->fetch_assoc())
        {
            $ID_Producto = $Fila_Productos['ID_Producto'];
        ?>

            <span data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo<?php echo $ID_Producto; ?>">Show ID <?php echo $ID_Producto ?></span>
            <div id="demo<?php echo $ID_Producto; ?>" class="collapse">
                <?php echo $ID_Producto; ?>
            </div>
            <br>

        <?php
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much , I really appreciate your help, I remember try that before but I don't know why did not work, thank you men :D